# Is there a graphical error in iPhone SDK 4 Cocoa Touch toolbars?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

Add a toolbar to a view in Interface Builder, and then add buttons to the toolbar.  Image buttons on a toolbar glow/highlight when they are tapped, to give the user a response that they touched it.  Ever since iPhone SDK 4 however, when tapping buttons in a toolbar, the glow is the correct size, but with every tap the glow gets progressively smaller, until it is eventually only about one pixel big after about 20 taps.  It is the same in both the simulator and the device.

Has anyone else experienced this?

(Yes, I realize this is so minor that it doesn't really matter, I just want to make sure that I'm not crazy and that it's Apple's fault and not mine.)

(will try to post screenshot ASAP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's Apple's fault. I found a couple of bugs before in 3.1.3. And they got fixed in 4.0. For example, a certain configuration of a search box doesn't resize properly when screen rotates.